# Xpath of a table cell based on the other cell in the same row

Tags: html, xpath, html-table

This is the html code I got:

```
<tr class="">
    <td>
        <a href="www.google.com">Go to Google</a>
    </td>
    <td>02/10/20, 09:24 AM</td>
    <td><button type="button" class="delete"></td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, the `<tr>` has three `<td>`s. Now, we are talking about a table, so we can assume that I have 100 of these `<tr>`s, with different values, but with the same structure. I would like to get the xpath of the third `td` (the `button`), using the value of `<a>` ('Go to Google'). How can I do that? I know I need to something like:

```
(//td//parent::a)
```

but evidently am not smart enough for that.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to find the `td` element that has a child `a` with the text “Go to Google”, and then from this `td` find the next `td` that has a `button` element child.

In XPath this could look like this:

```
//td[a[text()="Go to Google"]]/following-sibling::td[button]
```